# Tailwind grid missing cells when inside Alpine.js template

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I want to show a recipe as a 2 column grid, with one column for the ingredients and the other column for quantities. I'm using Alpine.js and Tailwind for this.

I create an Alpine template and loop through the ingredients array which contains 2 keys (name and qty). I use each key in a different div, but it behaves as if the array contained only ingredients names, skipping quantities. This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Simple Dough Recipe</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-purple-100">
    <div x-data="recipe()" class="p-10">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
            <template x-for="ingredient in ingredients">
                <div class="bg-red-700" x-text="ingredient.name">Ingredient</div>
                <div class="bg-green-700"  x-text="ingredient.qty">Qty</div>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 mt-10">
                <div class="bg-blue-700">Flour</div>
                <div class="bg-green-700">1000</div>
                <div class="bg-blue-700">Water</div>
                <div class="bg-green-700">600</div>
                <div class="bg-blue-700">Salt</div>
                <div class="bg-green-700">10</div>
                <div class="bg-blue-700">Yeast</div>
                <div class="bg-green-700">5</div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function recipe() {
        return {
            ingredients: [
                {name: 'Flour', qty: 1000},
                {name: 'Water', qty: 600},
                {name: 'Salt', qty: 10},
                {name: 'Yeast', qty: 5}
            ]
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've added a second grid to show the desired output. What am I missing?

[image]

I've tried using a table instead of a grid and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for `x-for` in Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for):

> `x-for` MUST be declared on a `<template>` element That `<template>` element MUST contain only one root element

Your `<template>` element contains two root elements. This violates the second aforementioned rule.

To work around this, consider wrapping both elements in a `<div>` and then apply [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents) via the `contents` class so that the CSS acts as though the root `<div>` does not exist, thus allowing your grid layout:

```js
function recipe() {
  return {
    ingredients: [
      {name: 'Flour', qty: 1000},
      {name: 'Water', qty: 600},
      {name: 'Salt', qty: 10},
      {name: 'Yeast', qty: 5}
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<body class="bg-purple-100">
  <div x-data="recipe()" class="p-10">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
      <template x-for="ingredient in ingredients">
        <div class="contents">
          <div class="bg-red-700" x-text="ingredient.name">Ingredient</div>
          <div class="bg-green-700"  x-text="ingredient.qty">Qty</div>
         </div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 mt-10">
      <div class="bg-blue-700">Flour</div>
      <div class="bg-green-700">1000</div>
      <div class="bg-blue-700">Water</div>
      <div class="bg-green-700">600</div>
      <div class="bg-blue-700">Salt</div>
      <div class="bg-green-700">10</div>
      <div class="bg-blue-700">Yeast</div>
      <div class="bg-green-700">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In understand. Thanks a lot.